# If G is abelian and $n>1$ is an integer, then $A=\{a^n \mid a \in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to proove:

> If $G$ is an abelian group, and we have $n>1 \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $A_n = \{a^n \mid a \in G\} $ is a subgroup for $G$ for all $n$.

To me, it looks like I need to prove by induction, with a base case of $n=2$, but I am unsure of how to prove the statement regardless.

Subgroup proofs typically use closure and inverses, but I am really new to groups and I am unsure of how to proceed. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you prove anything is a group? By showing the axioms for it. Why don't you list the axioms given in your textbook etc. in the above question, and try to verify them one by one? If it is difficult, then we are here, but at least that is how to proceed on this question.

Comment: I wouldn't do it by induction. There is no real connection between the $A$ you get for, for instance, $n=2$ and for $n=3$, so the base case would have to cover at least all the prime numbers. Just do it for a single, arbitrary $n$, and you're done. That being said, you _can_ do it for $n=2$ and $3$ first if you like, to get a feel for how a general proof would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}
&(1)\;\;1=1^n\\{}\\
&(2)\;\;\forall x,y\in G\;,\;\;(xy)^n=x^ny^n\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

To prove that a set is a subgroup, prove that:

1. The set is closed under the binary operation of $G$.
2. There is an identity element in the set.
3. There is an inverse for every element of the set in the set.

Note that associativity comes for free, since $G$ is a group.